# How to check if only specific table column affected in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently, I have controller & model for form edit. If user submit different value, this will modify the value in database and if there is an affected rows, will set flash message as "success" and if same data is submitted by user without modify the value,then will set flash message as "nochange".

```
           if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ) {
               $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Database is updated');
               redirect('registrar');
           } else {
               $this->session->set_flashdata('nochange','There is no changes in database');
               redirect('registrar');
           }
```

In Codeigniter, how can I check if only specific columns are affected?

For example, if my table in database have 12 columns, if user only change the value let say in column 10, then set flash message as "nochange".

If user changes values in other columns except column 10, set flash message as "success"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no in-built functionality in CodeIgniter or php to do this.

You would have to essentially get the entire entry before updating it. And then column by column compare the submitted value with the current value of the entry as per your required logic.

Example pseudo-code:

```
$q = $this->db->get_where('table', array('id' => $id))->row();

$change = false;

if ($this->input->post('col1') !== $q->col1) {
    $change = true;
}

...

if ($this->input->post('col10') == $q->col10) {
    $change = false;
}


$this->db->update('table', $data);
```